# JavaScript player that can play MP3 and show background image?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I am working on a website in which I am displaying audio/video content. For videos I am using HTML5 video tag. However, in case of audio, I need to play the audio as well as show an image in the audio player. Is there any html5/javascript player that supports showing of image in the player while playing audio content?

```html
<audio controls>
<source src="http://hcmaslov.d-real.sci-nnov.ru/public/mp3/Cranberries/Cranberries%20'Dreams'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/dc/Everybody_else_is_doing_it_so_why_can%27t_we_%28album_cover%29.jpg/220px-Everybody_else_is_doing_it_so_why_can%27t_we_%28album_cover%29.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<video>` and `<audio>` tags are almost identical, `<video>` tags have no trouble playing audio files. Use the `poster` attribute to display an image.

### Demo

```html
<video controls autoplay poster='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/dc/Everybody_else_is_doing_it_so_why_can%27t_we_%28album_cover%29.jpg/220px-Everybody_else_is_doing_it_so_why_can%27t_we_%28album_cover%29.jpg'>
<source src="http://home.saske.sk/~slavo/Audio/FOLK/Cranberries/The%20Cranberries%20-%20No%20Need%20To%20Argue/10%20-%20The%20Cranberries%20-%20Dreaming%20My%20Dreams.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```

Comment: Its not playing mp3 ... Can poster be displayed while displaying mp3 ?

Comment: Yep it played ... thanks ... I now see the audio controls .. had to scroll.

Comment: Ok, great, and you are welcome. Happy coding. Oh the controls? They popup when user hovers over the player...Ok good, I was about to rewrite the demo. :P